# How convert decimal number to Hexadecimal number by a script in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, hex, decimal, converters

I am using a bash file in Ubuntu and i wrote an executable code in this file that must use some Hexadecimal number.

But I just have decimal numbers , so I want to convert decimal numbers to Hexadecimal numbers automatically by some command.

This is a part of my code :

```
x=1
while [ $x -lt 255 ];do
$tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 10:0 prio 5 u32 ht 2:$x: \
match ip dst 192.168.67.$x flowid 10:$x
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

in this section "u32 ht 2:$x:" in my code "$x" must be in Hexadecimal form and in other section must be in decimal form.but my problem is in Hexadecimal form. How can i convert it in my code and use it ?

Comment: You use "in this file" **3** times in your first sentence; I'm sorry, I don't understand that sentence. Could you say what "this file" is at first, then split your sentence in multiple sentences and add paragraphs (empty lines between sentences) to make your question more clear?

Comment: What is `$tc`? Using variables to store parts of a command is not good practice. Also, the parts of an IP address should not go above 255, so I think that you should change your loop.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok. tanks .I edited my question

Comment: @TomFenech this is a small part of my code and tc is a package for traffic shaping . but my problem is to convert $x to Hexadecimal form to use in this section 2:$x:

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/897756/4714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert decimal number to hexadecimal with bash builtin commands:

```
dec=123
printf -v hex "%x" $dec
echo $hex
```

Output:

```
7b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bc`

```
dec=123
bc <<< "obase=16;$dec"
```

Output:

```
7B
```